# Can same program run as Server as well as client for others in java?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am working on this problem where I have couple of machines on network. Which should communicate with each others with socket. So basic idea is program running on every machine should work as Client as well as Server? Is it possible to do so? If it is can anyone direct me to appropriate resources?

Sumit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But you will have to have both functionalities in different threads.

Comment: Note that [NIO support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) allows Java to use standard non-blocking IO -- allowing Java programs to avoid multiple threads.

Comment: "At this point, you have to wait on the selector to tell you when events of interest happen on registered channels. The select method of the Selector will block until something interesting happens. To find this out, you can put a while (selector.select() > 0) loop in its own thread and then go off and do your own thing while the I/O events are being processed. The select method returns when something happens, where the value returned is the count of channels ready to be acted upon. This value doesn't really matter though." - http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/nio/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Apache River](http://river.apache.org/)